# The tricky prepositions. . . "in my garden"

Tags: grammar, preposition

I think prepositions are tricky in every language. The other day I was trying to figure out how to write correctly : In my garden there are many fruit-trees. The first sentence I thought of was:

在我花园里有很多果树

But I felt there was something wrong. So I put up some other alternatives:

我花园上有很多果树
Or maybe better to cancel "wo", although the meaning is changing a little. 
花园里有很多果树

花园中有很多果树
在花园中。 。 。

Or should I use 上？
在我花园上有很多果树

Would it be better to cancel the "you"
Or even change it with "zhan"

花园里站很多果树？

So - a simple sentence turned into a riddle. I will appreciate suggestions and explanations why I should use whatever sentence you suggest is better.

Answer (score 4):

在我花园里有很多果树 is the most accurate.

上 means on, on top of. If you use 上 people will think your garden has a roof, and those fruit trees are planted on the roof.

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/view/256231.htm

站 invokes the image of standing on one's feet in a stiff, rigid, upright manner. unless you want to emphasize the upright, honest and steadfast manner of some pine or poplar trees, most garden trees are everything but stiff.

Source : http://baike.baidu.com/view/259393.htm

Comment: Im glad it seems that my feeling for Mandaring is not that bad after all, but the reason why I thought adding perhaps 上 was an option (or even compulsory), is that sometimes you really use 上 a little differently, for instance, if you are in bed, one has to say 我在床上 and not 我在床里。 But that still means you are IN bed, not on the top of your bed. Right?

Comment: Right.the first time I learn this I had to memorize it as a special case. Now the English way actually makes sense if, by bed, they also include bedclothes, etc.

Comment: I'd say get rid of the “在” in front.

Comment: @Justin agreed. It's optional.

Answer (score 3):

Simply write: 我的花園有很多果樹. or 我的花園種了很多果樹.

(Now you know why some people wrote Chinglish like "My garden has many fruit trees." or "My garden grows many fruit trees.")

For spoken Mandarin, I am not sure.  :)